# How to manage common frontend components on microservices

Tags: architecture, frontend, single-page-application, microservices, orchestration

How to manage frontend on microservices, especially when you have common components? I found a few solutions on the internet but all of them have some drawbacks and none of them is a good fit for us.

Let me clearify my problem. We have over 5 groups of people working on different microservices in a large single project. And almost all of them has some common,shared components on frontend. And these components are huge as they are already a different project but totally shared. Now how to manage these shared components or should we duplicate them?

First solution I found is to make those components shared and maintain from a single point like node packages and npm install when needed from different groups. But at this point the microservice approach is broken since everybody will be dependent to these components and no one will be able to maintain as soon as they need, not good. And very hard to maintain since in the future different groups may different needs from the component.

Second is to duplicate the components according to each project and develop within the microservice group but this time it becomes very frankenstein and the common concepts that we should obey are hard to catch. It's a really enterprise project that all components should match in terms of behaivor and look to the other components reoccured in the project.

So we need a frontend solution for microservices that should be suitable for an enterprise project which is needed to obey same rules(like font size,color,actions etc..) at different points as it is monolithly written, but maintainable by different groups at the same time.

How can we balance that or can we?

Thanks to @kayess: Shortly how to apply shared kernel on microservices as the teams will not be dependent to each other?

Comment: To me it sounds like if you are asking for [shared kernel](https://herbertograca.com/2016/02/05/ddd-14-maintaining-model-integrity/) and [this](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/02/ddd-microservices) from DDD terminology.

Comment: I looked for shared kernel and it is defined as "An agreed subset of the system might be shared between different teams. Strict coordination rules apply." which exactly match what we want.  Now question is like how to apply shared kernel on microservices as the teams are not dependent to each other.

Comment: I think that you should edit this information throughly into your question to get  concise answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

> First solution I found is to make those components shared and maintain
>   from a single point like node packages and npm install when needed
>   from different groups. But at this point the microservice approach is
>   broken since everybody will be dependent to these components

I believe your understanding of a microservice is wrong. Fowler's definition of a microservice:

> In short, the microservice architectural style [1](http://semver.org/) is an approach to
>   developing a single application as a suite of small services, each
>   running in its own process and communicating with lightweight
>   mechanisms, often an HTTP resource API.

It's ok for microservices in your company to have common components. Microservices are much higher level of abstraction, than a component. Do not try to make every component a microservice.

You should manage your components in separate repository each. Use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) to publish updates and watch over compatibility breaks.

> And very hard to maintain since in the future different groups may
>   different needs from the component.

I do not believe this is hard to maintain. The maintainability of your configuration is certainly not higher, than that of any framework around since millions of programmers depend on those frameworks and develop them together. It's a quesion of maintainer's skill.

You can go with a monolithic repository approach (put all the components into a single, but standalone repo), but I think this will mess up things pretty quickly.

Comment: You catched some points but I think we are not on the very same path. We  dont try to make each component a microservice. As you said microservice is much higher abstraction. But we want to use the same components in those different microservices. It is like we got microservice "A" and "B" and there is a "componentA" which should be used on both teams. A and B are using same services sometimes, same apis and we got cdc tests for those that is no problem to and every microservice has bffs to convert those apis to its own domain.

Comment: But here the problem is frontend, the componentA is a frontend component and should be maintainable with all microservices unlike an api. Apis are  under microservices responsibilty and bffs are like those too and to maintain them are easy and they are binding microservices but frontend should be under all teams responsibilty we can not divide like bffs. I hope I could explain.

Comment: @wertigom Your problem is not a technical one, but the organizational. Use semantic versioning to maintain same (or compatible) component versions across your microservices. Copy / pasting component code will bring you nightmare.